# Can someone please clarify this example from G.H. Hardy "Course of Pure Mathematics" (Chapter 1 Misc. Ex. 34 )

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please help me understand a solution of this misc. problem from G.H. Hardy "Course of Pure Mathematics":

"If $a_0x^n + a_1x^{n−1} + · · · + a_n = 0$, where $a_0, a_1, . . . , a_n$ are any algebraical numbers, then $x$ is an algebraical
number."

He provides a solution:

[We have $n + 1$ equations of the type

$a_0,_ra^{m_r}_r + a_1,_ra^{m_r−1}_r + · · · + a_{m_r},_r = 0$ $(r = 0, 1, . . . , n)$,

in which the coefficients $a_0,_r, a_1,_r, . . .$ are integers. Eliminate $a_0, a_1, . . . , a_n$
between these and the original equation for x.]

But how am I suppose to perform this "elimination"?

So lets say I have a specific equation like:

$x^2 - 2x\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} = 0$

Since each coefficient is algebraic number, as per above, am I suppose to take equations:

$1^2 a_0,_1 + 1 a_1,_1 + a_2,_1 = 0$

$(2\sqrt{2})^2 a_0,_2 + 2\sqrt{2} a_1,_2 + a_2,_2 = 0$

$(\sqrt{3})^2 a_0,_3 + \sqrt{3} a_1,_3 + a_2,_3 = 0$

An then how am I suppose to "eliminate" $1, 2\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$

Thanks,

Comment: Your question should not be in the link.

Comment: Understood, fixed